# Let $X$ be an infinite countable bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$,Then which of following is true

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Given that $X$ is an infinite countable  bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ .Then which of the following is true

> $1).$ $X$ cannot be compact
>
> $2).$ $X$ contains an interior point
>
> $3).$ closure of $X$ is countable

**solution i tried**

> $1).$ if we suppose an example $\displaystyle \left \{ \frac{1}{n} :n \in \mathbb{N} \right \}\bigcup\left\{0\right\}$ which is bounded and countable and also have its limit point in it

thus this set is bounded and closed $\Rightarrow$ compact

> $2)$.Similarly if we suppose that $\displaystyle \left \{ \frac{1}{n} :n \in \mathbb{N} \right \}$ then this is infinte countable bounded set but have no interior point

So both $1$ and $2$  options are false but i am getting confused how to think about $3$ option ,if we consider example used in $1$ part then this is true ,but from one example we can't say it will always true

Please provide me a hint so that i can solve further

Thankyou

Comment: Consider the rationals in $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

Remember the rationals are *dense*.  That's $\Bbb Q$ is countable, but with uncountable closure.  So, take $\Bbb Q\cap B$, where $B$ is an interval, say.